# How do I fix this ANTRL4, scanner precedence error?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm puzzled by the behavior of the following grammar.

```
grammar MyParser;

options {
    caseInsensitive = true;
}

// Parser Rules


parameterName
    : DOLLAR_SIGN separatedIdentifier
    ;

separatedIdentifier
    : EXTENDED_IDENTIFER
    ;

// Scanner Rules


DOLLAR_SIGN: '$';

EXTENDED_IDENTIFER
    : IDENTIFIER_EXTEND+
    ;

IDENTIFIER_START
    : ID_Start
    | Pc
    ;

IDENTIFIER_EXTEND
    : ID_Continue
    | Sc
    ;

fragment ID_Continue
    : [\p{ID_Continue}]
    ;

fragment Sc
    : [\p{Sc}]
    ;
```

When enter this grammar and the input "$michael" in ANTLR Lab, I get the following error and parse tree.

```
1:0 missing '$' at '$michael'
```

[image]

Can someone explain why the '$' is not consumed as DOLLAR_SIGN and instead appears to be consumed as part of EXTENDED_IDENTIFIER?

I realize that EXTENDED_IDENTIFIER can contain a '$', because of the inclusion of the Sc fragment in the rule. But shouldn't the lexer consume the '$' first as part of DOLLAR_SIGN. I don't understand why it appears to be looking ahead and instead consuming it as part of EXTENDED_IDENTIFIER.

And how can I fix this grammar?

p.s. This is part of a bigger grammar that uses EXTENDED_IDENTIFIER from other rules.

Answer (score 1):

The $ character is not recognized as a `DOLLAR_SIGN` token, because of the first rule of [how the lexer chooses token rules](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/wildcard.md#:%7E:text=Here%20is%20how,go%20into%20here.) ("The primary goal is to match the lexer rule that recognizes the most input characters.")

Without changing the `EXTENDED_IDENTIFER` rule you won't change this behavior.  And, given its context it does not appear that that is an option.

You have a couple of options.

- Drop the `parameterName` parser rule and handle this aspect of your processing in the semantic phase (in your own code after you've done syntactic processing to construct the parse tree).  This is preferable if the desired parse tree is identical whether you have a `parameterName` or a `separatedIdentifier`.  (I can't determine that from your simplified grammar).  It moves the determination of whether you have a `parameterName` into your own code and probably allows you to give more informative diagnostics.
- Introduce a semantic predicate into the `parameterName` rule.  This will introduce target language specific code into your grammar, and this can lead to issues later on if you want to generate parsers for multiple targets (maybe Java and JavaScript, for example).  The change would look like this:

```java
parameterName
    : {getCurrentToken().getText().startsWith("$")}?EXTENDED_IDENTIFER
    ;
```

Now I've introduced java code to your grammar, but you get this result.

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;

public class TestComp {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        new TestComp().run(CharStreams.fromString("$michael"));
        new TestComp().run(CharStreams.fromString("michael"));
    }

    public void run(CharStream charStream) {
        var lexer = new MyParserLexer(charStream);
        var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new MyParserParser(tokenStream);
        var either = parser.either();
        System.out.println(either.toStringTree(parser));
    }
}
```

with added parser rule:

```
either: parameterName | separatedIdentifier;
```

produces output:

```
(either (parameterName $michael))
(either (separatedIdentifier michael))
```

NOTE: It doesn't appear that lab.antlr.org supports parser predicates